# Accessing Tcl namespace variables from imported procedures

Tags: variables, namespaces, tcl

I'm fairly new to Tcl, and I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
namespace eval foo {
    namespace export bar
    proc bar {} {
        puts $bob
    }
}

namespace eval fred {
    namespace import foo::*
    variable bob ""
}

fred::bar
```

However, I'm finding that bar is being called within the scope of foo, and so it tells me that foo::bob doesn't exist.

How can I make it so that fred::bar will access fred::bob?

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to pretend to do OO? If so, why not use a _real_ object system? (If you're using Tcl 8.6, it definitely comes with TclOO and should come with [incr Tcl] as well. I wrote TclOO…)

Comment: Effectively, yes, but I'm not sure whether it's Tcl 8.6 I'm using, and I don't have much time to learn about OO in Tcl. I also don't want to deviate too far away from some existing code.

In the end, I defined my functions in the global namespace (since I wasn't intending to redefine them in other namespaces), and just passed in the namespace name to retrieve the correct variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic question is why are you trying to do it?

It is not a style that is typically used with Tcl namespaces. Actually even `namespace import` isn't used that much.

This is a very brittle design, makes testing harder and hides the dependencies of the proc bar. So it is probably bad style to try to do things this way.

You can of course do something like that, but it tends to get weird and would need a specially crafted proc `bar`, this works, but is pretty ugly:

```
namespace eval foo {
    namespace export bar
    proc bar {} {
        if {[info level 0] eq [namespace origin [info level 0]]} {
           # called from our native namespace...
           puts "Oops."
        } else {
           set foreign_ns ::[namespace qualifiers [info level 0]]
           namespace upvar $foreign_ns bob bob
           puts $bob
        }
    }
}

namespace eval fred {
    namespace import ::foo::*
    variable bob "hello bob"
}

fred::bar
```

prints "hello bob".

So maybe try to explain what you really want to do with this kind of import in a different question, and there might be a more useful answer.

Comment: I realize this isn't intended as a real working solution, but even as an example I think it would be better to use `namespace upvar $foreign_ns bob bob` instead of `set varname ${foreign_ns}::bob` so you can have `puts $bob` as in the question.